# Python multiprocessing manager queue registry

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, queue, freeze

In the following code I tried to implement a class to handle mappings between a name and a multiprocessing manager queue.
The example contains a short test programm for debugging reasons.

Later on, different processes should be able to get queues by name
and exchange data over those queues.
Unfortunately, there is no possibility to pass queue references between processes, in my case.

I don't know why, but the code hangs in the `add_queue` method. If I exchange `self.mp_namespace.queues[name] = self.mp_manager.Queue()` with
`self.mp_namespace.queues[name] = self.mp_manager.list()`, the code does not hang.

There are related examples in the documentation https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/multiprocessing.html#managers of the multiprocessing package,
in the namespace and the proxy section.

Why can I add plain old datatypes or a list to a Namespace but no Queue?
Do you have any suggestion how to fix the issue with the blocking call?

```
import multiprocessing

class NamedManagerQueues:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mp_manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        self.mp_namespace = self.mp_manager.Namespace()
        self.mp_namespace.queues = self.mp_manager.dict()

    def add_queue(self, name: str):
        self.mp_namespace.queues[name] = self.mp_manager.Queue()

    def get_queue(self, name: str):
        return self.mp_namespace.queues[name]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nq = NamedManagerQueues()
    nq.add_queue("q1")
    q = nq.get_queue("q1")
    q.put("bla")
    elem = q.get(timeout=0.1)
```

Comment: your code seems to work for me (3.10.8) and will generate the expected output if I add in `print(elem)`.

Comment: Do you use windows or linux? I'm using linux wth python 3.10. https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues/6188

Comment: Both. Specific Linux version is 3.10.11

Comment: Hhm, when I run it from console, it works for me, too. Maybe strange IDE or debugger issue? I use PyCharm 2023.2

Comment: I have opened an `jetbrains` issue and will wait what they say. If it turns out as an IDE issue I will delete the question. Meanwhile I would like too keep it. If that's OK?

Comment: If you have an issue, I see no reason to delete it. Others might be in the same boat. For what it is worth, I use VSCode.